# How to get page 2 from paginated records

Tags: laravel, lumen

into a Laravel Lumen API project, I want to get page 2 of the paginated records. But it gives me back no result.

```
$query = DB::table('cars');
$query->paginate(2, ['*'], 'page', 2);
$data = $query->get();
```

How can I realize it?

Thanks for help.

Comment: may be your cars table has count === 2 or less that it so it will have only page one

Comment: no
$records = $query->count();
shows 218

Comment: check my answer

Comment: you can use page number as query params to fetch records from a specific page, of course after paginating the items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as you can your code

> Adding the table to builder instance

`$query = DB::table('cars');` **Looks Fine**

> Paginate the Builder

`$query->paginate(2, ['*'], 'page', 2);` **Looks Fine**

But You can You are not **chaning** with the prevoius method so the pagination will be applied but you can't access so

`$paginated = $query->paginate(2, ['*'], 'page', 2);` **Will Work Fine**

**EDITED**

As You Said No Changes in Record its because you have hardcoded the page number

So

`$paginated = $query->paginate(2, ['*'], 'page');` **Will Work Perfectly**

AFTER REMOVING THE LAST Argument **2** from function

Now the $paginated  will giv the LengthAwarePaginatorInstance

So You need to pass `$paginated` to **Json**

Hope it is clear

Comment: I understand.
I tried it hardcode with page 1 and page 2 and it works.

Now I tried to make it dynamic from parameter.

    $limit = (Input::get('limit') ? Input::get('limit') : '10');
    $page = (Input::get('page') ? Input::get('page') : 1);
    $paginated = $query->paginate($limit, ['*'], 'page', $page);

    {{domain-url}}/api/v1/cars?limit=10&page=2

But this does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Pagination in Lumen should work the same as Laravel.

According to the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination#basic-usage

To get any page number of the paginated results, set the send ?page query string parameter with the page you'd like to retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

To paginate records in Lumen/Laravel, just use the `paginate()` function. It accept the page number as query parameters, you don't need to explicitly define that.

Also you don't need to add `->get()` with `paginate()`.

// For the second page the url would be as:

```
http://example.com/something?page=2
```

// Paginator code would be as

```
$data = DB::table('cars')->paginate(2);
```

Here parameter (2) represents limit - no of records to be display.